# How to denote remainder in a paper in science?

Tags: publications, mathematics, formatting, science

I want to write a result in a scientific paper that contains the remainder of X (a real number) divided by R (another real number), i.e. X - [X/R]R, where [X/R] is the floor function. Is there an appropriate notation for this? For example, X%R?

Comment: _X mod R_ is often used.

Comment: X mod R. But this is probably the wrong site, the https://math.stackexchange.com/ or https://tex.stackexchange.com/ might be more suitable.

Comment: @Buffy Isn't X mod R only for integers?

Comment: Not really. But if you are doing computing, rather than mathematics, note that there are various inconsistent definitions depending on the language. Especially for negative values.

Comment: I use X % R much of the time (with the caveat that it's "\%" in LaTeX, since "%" alone starts a comment). Do not use "mod"; it already means the residue class, which is not the same thing. (2 % 5 + 3 % 5 is not the same as 5 % 5; but 2 mod 5 + 3 mod 5 is the same as 5 mod 5.)

Answer (score 1):

You can write it out in words as you did in the question.

Comment: Or define any symbol you want to use in a foot or endnote.

Comment: @Buffy in my field symbols are defined in the text.